# How to show the hint of a first-level TMainMenu item on MouseOver without opening the menu?

Tags: delphi, menu, tooltip, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TMainMenu` with a hint on each menu item:

[image]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.AppEvnts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    mFile: TMenuItem;
    mEdit: TMenuItem;
    mOpen: TMenuItem;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Hint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  CodeSiteLogging;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Hint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CodeSite.Send('TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Hint: Application.Hint', Application.Hint);
end;

end.
```

This is the DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 366
  ClientWidth = 639
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -15
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  Position = poScreenCenter
  ShowHint = True
  PixelsPerInch = 120
  TextHeight = 20
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 248
    Top = 144
    object mFile: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'File'
      Hint = 'Click here to open the File menu'
      object mOpen: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Open'
        Hint = 'Click here to open a File'
      end
    end
    object mEdit: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Edit'
      Hint = 'Click here to open the Edit menu'
    end
  end
  object ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents
    OnHint = ApplicationEvents1Hint
    Left = 248
    Top = 160
  end
end
```

When I hover the mouse pointer over the "File" menu item, there is NO Application hint! Only after OPENING the File menu, I do get an `Application.Hint` when hovering the mouse pointer over the "File" menu item.

So how can I get notified when hovering the mouse pointer over the `mFile` menu item without opening the menu?

Comment: This is how Windows works, and it has been like this since at least Windows 95: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Zek.gif

Comment: Yes, I agree. But for most Windows annoyances, there are tricks to circumvent them. Is there a trick for this question too?

Comment: Almost certainly, but I'm not sure I can find the time to investigate this today.

Comment: Any user can **enter** the menu without **opening** it by simply pressing (and releasing) either the `Alt` or `F10` key - would this suffice your needs?

Comment: Hi Amigojack, I just need to get notified when the mouse pointer hovers over `mFile` while the menu is still closed.

Comment: Do what I wrote, then hover/move your mouse cursor - the menu remains "closed" and your hint event is triggered. Menus can also be controlled by keyboard alone, so don't reduce your goals to mouse input only.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to react on mouse cursor movements (and not on keyboard input) then process the [`WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-ncmousemove) message:

```delphi
interface

  TfrmMain= class( TForm )
    mnuMain: TMainMenu;  // The menu, containing at least one top item
  protected
    procedure WmNcMouseMove(var vMsg: TWMNCMouseMove); message WM_NCMOUSEMOVE;
  end;

implementation

procedure TfrmMain.WmNcMouseMove(var vMsg: TWMNCMouseMove);
var
  iItem: Integer;
  vR: TRect;
  vP: TPoint;
  oItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  inherited;

  // Only react to menu related mouse cursor moves
  if vMsg.HitTest= HTMENU then begin
    oItem:= nil;  // Not found yet

    for iItem:= 0 to self.mnuMain.Items.Count- 1 do begin  // All topmost items
      if GetMenuItemRect( self.Handle, self.mnuMain.Handle, iItem, vR ) then begin
        // Also checking Y is needed, as a menu can have more than 1 line.
        // Consider sizing your window width to the minimum to see this effect.
        vP.X:= vMsg.XCursor;
        vP.Y:= vMsg.YCursor;
        if PtInRect( vR, vP ) then begin  // X>= left< right; Y>= top< bottom
          oItem:= self.mnuMain.Items[iItem];  // Found the item under the mouse cursor
          break;
        end;
      end else break;  // Makes no sense to continue on any error
    end;

    // Now get the .hint or otherwise display empty text
    if oItem<> nil then self.Caption:= oItem.Hint else self.Caption:= '';
  end else self.Caption:= '';  // Any other NC area should reset text, too
end;
```

- Successfully tested with Delphi 7 on Windows 7 x64 with themes disabled (Windows 95 look), 1 monitor only and the menu having 1 or even 2 lines (very short window width): hovering the mouse cursor over the menu items without clicking them will display the correct hint.
- Maybe a desktop spanning multiple monitors needs additional work.
- Covering keyboard input (<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>) is already done with your code (`TApplicationEvents.OnHint`).
- Discovered [`GetMenuItemRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647981.aspx) in [Delphi: Menu Hint bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512248/4299358) 
   and `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` in [Not receiving WM_NCHitTest on title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661699/4299358).
- [`PtInRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ptinrect) compares X and Y accurately: X `>=` left of the rectangle, but X `<` right (not `<=`); same for Y. Only left/top are inclusive, while right/bottom are exclusive.

Comment: This did not work for me, so I changed the logic: See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the logic of your idea which is great!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.AppEvnts, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    mFile: TMenuItem;
    mEdit: TMenuItem;
    mOpen: TMenuItem;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Hint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WmNcMouseMove(var vMsg: TWMNCMouseMove); message WM_NCMOUSEMOVE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  CodeSiteLogging;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Hint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := Application.Hint;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.WmNcMouseMove(var vMsg: TWMNCMouseMove);
var
  iItem: Integer;
  vR: TRect;
  oItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  inherited;
  
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := '';

  if vMsg.HitTest = HTMENU then
  begin
    oItem := nil;

    for iItem := 0 to Self.MainMenu1.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if GetMenuItemRect(Self.Handle, Self.MainMenu1.Handle, iItem, vR) then
      begin
        if (vMsg.XCursor >= vR.Left) and (vMsg.XCursor <= vR.Right) and (vMsg.YCursor >= vR.Top) and (vMsg.YCursor <= vR.Bottom) then
        begin
          oItem := Self.MainMenu1.Items[iItem];
          BREAK;
        end;
      end
      else
        BREAK;
    end;

    if Assigned(oItem) then
      StatusBar1.SimpleText := oItem.Hint;
  end;
end;

end.
```

What do you think?

Comment: Now `.SimpleText` won't be reset anymore when the mouse cursor is in the menu but not highlighting any item. And `TForm.OnMouseMove` is not enough - you're better off simply adding an `else` when `.HitTest` is not `HTMENU`, so the text is also reset if moving to the window title or any other non-client (that's what NC means) area. Also removing comments is mostly a bad idea.

Comment: It works for me. Try it out by using the above code.

Comment: Why not use `PtInRect` function to check which item the cursor is on?

Comment: @yonni That should have been a comment on my answer - indeed I was using 1 pixel too much for right/bottom, while `PtInRect()`'s documentation explains it checks differently and correctly.

Comment: Look at the SCREENSHOTS.

Comment: A bit off topic, but for what it's worth: The convention when it comes to menu item (and control) hints is that they describe the action performed in third-person present tense: `Creates a new frog.`, `Opens an existing frog.`, `Saves the current frog to file.`, `Sends the current frog's image and data to a printer.`, `Exits the application.`, etc. Menu items that only serve as submenu parents typically have hints like `Contains view settings.`, `Contains actions you can perform on the currently selected frog(s).`, `Contains various application settings.`, etc.

Comment: At least that's the Windows 9x convention and the convention I have been following for the last 25 years! https://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/rte_screenshots.asp#menus

Comment: Dear Andreas, it's time to become creative and change Windows for the better.

Comment: "_Click here to_" is redundant and everyone who read it 10 times already will lose interest in those textes still to come. If the desktop/monitor is tiny and the window's width very short you on top will always read that prosa while the useful info falls off. Unless all of your users need an explanation for how menus work again and again. Plus: "clicking" is not the only action - think of tablets, where you touch - that's also a reason to avoid implied action terms. Also: end sentences with punctuation, otherwise the user cannot distinguish it from cut off texts.